# How do I receive post from a form where I name an input as <?php echo $var ?>?

Tags: php, html

I tried `$_POST['<?php echo $var ?>`] but I should have known that it wouldn't be that easy.

The reason why I try to do is because I have several input boxes with values I take from a database and I'm trying to create an updation script where any of the input box values can be changed.

for example

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<?php
while($variable=mysql_fetch_array($sqlconnec))
{
?>   
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $variable['col1']?>" value="<?php echo   $variable['val'] ?>" />
<?php 
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: put your while loop with in php tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $col; ?>" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" />

$_POST[$col] //this will have the input value defined above.
```

In process.php you have to do the same query as mentioned above. If you iterate through those results $_POST[$col] will contain the posted values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<?php
$variable = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlconnec);
foreach($variable as $col => $val)
{
?>
   <input type="text" name="<?php echo $col; ?>" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now, `mysql_fetch_assoc` gets you the database row in a associative array. Then, the code iterates each column in the row and displays the name/value pair for it. And yes, you were not closing the value tag correctly.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() also can fetch the associative array

Comment: @Shakti, yes I know but `mysql_fetch_assoc` is more clear as its name fully suggests what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
//do something with $v or $_POST[$k]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to change the name of the input to something that is constant.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="testname" value="<?php echo $variable['val'] ? />
```

And then retrieve your variable like so:

```
$_POST['testname']
```

For example you could print the variable you sent in the input to test it like so:

```
echo $_POST['testname'];
```

Comment: This will give problems if you have more then 1 field. Since all of them will have the same ID: 1. The HTML will be invalid 2. The PHP script will only see 1 posted var.

Comment: @gnur, That's true. I wasn't clear on what the asker wanted. The point is, a known in advance variable should be used. If there are many input fields, then we can index them: `testname1`, `testname2`. Another answer shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your input 'value' tag with ". Also your second php closing tag is incorrect.

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $variable['col1']?>" value="<?php echo $variable['val'] ?>" />
```